# Contradiction in classical analysis of the hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}=xp$?

Tags: mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

I am writing an essay on the Berry Keating article proposing to use the $\mathcal{H}=xp$ hamiltonian to get a correspondence between the nontrivial riemann zeros and the eigenvalues of an Hermitian operator. Now classically, the time evolution of the system as follows from the Hamilton equations is:

$$ x(t)=x(0)e^t
$$
$$p(t) = p(0)e^{-t}
$$

It seems as if the particle is accelerating (since $\frac{dx}{dt}$ clearly increases), while $p$ obviously decreases. Moreover I do not immediately see how this system is chaotic, although clearly the distance as a result of different initial conditions between particles increases over time. Could you please shed some light on this?

Comment: Where is the contradiction? $p$ is not the classical *momentum* $p=m \dot{x}$ here. Indeed Hamilton equations just say that $\dot{x} = x$, differently from the case ${\cal H}= p^2/2m + U(x)$ where $\dot{x}= p/m$. The Hamiltonian decides what is the relation between $x$ and $p$...

Comment: ok thank you, i already thought something like that. But that also means that the momentum quantum operator is also different (it is different from $\frac{d}{dx}$ at least)?

Comment: also, do you know in which sense the system is chaotic then (equivalently what definition of chaos should be applied here?)

Comment: No it does not mean that. Regarding the second question, I do not know, since I do not know the definition of *chaotic*. However the Hamiltonian flow does not seem very ``chaotic'' to me in this case, as the maximal solutions are the trivial ones you wrote!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/384151/2451